# Regular expression - replace all spaces in beginning of line with periods

Tags: python, regex, vim, awk, sed

I don't care if I achieve this through vim, sed, awk, python etc. I tried in all, could not get it done.

For an input like this:

```
top           f1    f2    f3
   sub1       f1    f2    f3
   sub2       f1    f2    f3
      sub21   f1    f2    f3
   sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

I want:

```
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

Then I want to just load this up in Excel (delimited by whitespace) and still be able to look at the hierarchy-ness of the first column!

I tried many things, but end up losing the hierarchy information

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "load this up in Excel". You want to have it formatted so that it pastes well into a spreadsheet? Is this part of your question or are you just asking how to replace the leading whitespace with dots?

Comment: @CAustin sorry for the confusion.. the 'excel' part is not really a question, just the reason why i want what i want.

Comment: `I tried in all, could not get it done`... you should add at least one of them here... else question would look as asking code for free...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this as the input:

```
$ cat file
top           f1    f2    f3
   sub1       f1    f2    f3
   sub2       f1    f2    f3
      sub21   f1    f2    f3
   sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

Try:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/^( *) ([^ ])/\1.\2/; ta' file
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

#### How it works:

- `:a`

  This creates a label `a`.
- `s/^( *) ([^ ])/\1.\2/`

  If the line begins with spaces, this replaces the last space in the leading spaces with a period.

  In more detail, `^( *)`  matches all leading blanks except the last and stores them in group 1.  The regex `([^ ])` (which, despite what stackoverflow makes it look like, consists of a blank followed by `([^ ])`) matches a blank followed by a nonblank and stores the nonblank in group 2.

  `\1.\2` replaces the matched text with group 1, followed by a period, followed by group 2.
- `ta`

  If the substituted command resulted in a substitution, then branch back to label `a` and try over again.

#### Compatibility:

1. The above was tested on modern GNU sed.  For BSD/OSX sed, one might or might not need to use:

   ```
   sed -E -e :a -e 's/^( *) ([^ ])/\1.\2/' -e ta file
   ```

   On ancient GNU sed, one needs to use `-r` in place of `-E`:

   ```
   sed -r ':a; s/^( *) ([^ ])/\1.\2/; ta' file
   ```
2. The above assumed that the spaces were blanks.  If they are tabs, then you will have to decide what your tabstop is and make substitutions accordingly.

Comment: My head bows down in respect to the clarity of your answer. Thanks for the compatibility section - turns out my work machine uses 'ancient GNU sed' and '-r' was needed. Furthermore, I am in awe of the power of 'sed' with respect to labels and 'try over again' capability. It is shockingly awesome, and so are you!

Comment: @shikhanshu You're welcome and thank you for the very kind words!

Comment: It should work without the second backreference : `sed -E ':a;s/^( *) /\1./g;ta;' file`

Answer (score 5):

There are two different ways to do this in vim.

1. With a regex:

   ```
   :%s/^\s\+/\=repeat('.', len(submatch(0)))
   ```

   This is fairly straightforward, but a little verbose. It uses the eval register (`\=`) to generate a string of `'.'`s the same length as the number of spaces at the beginning of each line.
2. With a norm command:

   ```
   :%norm ^hviwr.
   ```

   This is a much more conveniently short command, although it's a little harder to understand. It visually selects the spaces at the beginning of a line, and replaces the whole selection with dots. If there is no leading space, the command will fail on `^h` because the cursor attempts to move out of bounds.

   To see how this works, try typing `^hviwr.` on a line that has leading spaces to see it happen.

Comment: Both the regex and norm command work perfect. I tried on a line with no leading space without ^h and I understood why ^h is needed :) Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

Since you said **`python`**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re, sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub('^ +', lambda m: len(m.group(0)) * '.', line))
```

(for each line, we replace the longest run of prefix spaces `'^ +'` with an equally long string of dots, `len(m.group(0)) * '.'`).

With the end result:

```
$ ./dottify.py <file
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

---

Since you said **`awk`**:

```
$ awk '{ match($0,/^ +/); p=substr($0,0,RLENGTH); gsub(" ",".",p); print p""substr($0,RLENGTH+1) }' file
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

(where for each line we match the longest prefix of spaces with [`match`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-match-regexp-in-string), extract it with [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-substring), replace each space with dot via [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-gsub_0028_0029-function-1), and print that modified prefix `p`, followed by the remainder of the input line (`RSTART` and `RLENGTH` variables are populated after `match()` and hold the starting position and length of the matched pattern).

Comment: Python one is so neat! The 'awk' one must have required some serious thought, thanks for the nice explanation! I wish I could chose more than one answers on SO

Answer (score 3):

In awk. It keeps replacing the first space with a period while the space is preceeded only by periods:

```
$ awk '{while(/^\.* / && sub(/ /,"."));}1' file
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

and here's one in perl:

```
$ perl -p -e 'while(s/(^\.*) /\1./){;}' file
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

Comment: well, if you are using perl, use the `e` feature...  `perl -pe 's/^ */"." x length($&)/e'`

Comment: you and your quest for short one-liners :P then yours can be shortened to `perl -pe 'while(s/^\.*\K /./){}'` .... but my point was more about performance ;)

Comment: That is pretty fast, btw. With a million records and 4 spaces in the beginning it's starting to make a difference to the other solutions (well, I only tested mine, the `sed` and the other awk). Then again this was a bit faster: `gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{i=1;while($i==" ")$(i++)="."}1' file` (on my biased laptop :).

Comment: you should totally post the speed tests to answer :)

Comment: Clever approach and elegant `awk` solution. Nice!

Comment: [TIL about \G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49996636/replace-leading-whitespace-with-other-other-char-python)... you can shorten that further to `perl -pe 's/\G /./g'`

Answer (score 1):

A little lengthy, but a fun exercise nonetheless:

```
# Function to count the number of leading spaces in a string
# Basically, this counts the number of consecutive elements that satisfy being spaces
def count_leading_spaces(s):
    if not s:
        return 0
    else:
        curr_char = s[0]
        if curr_char != ' ':
            return 0
        else:
            idx = 1
            curr_char = s[idx]
            while curr_char == ' ':
                idx += 1
                try:
                    curr_char = s[idx]
                except IndexError:
                    return idx
        return idx
```

Finally, open up the file and do some work:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        # Don't do anything to the field names
        if i == 0:
            new_line = line.rstrip()
        else:
            n_leading_spaces = count_leading_spaces(line)
            # Impute periods for spaces
            new_line = ('.'*n_leading_spaces + line.lstrip()).rstrip()
        data.append(new_line)
```

Results:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(data))
top           f1    f2    f3
...sub1       f1    f2    f3
...sub2       f1    f2    f3
......sub21   f1    f2    f3
...sub3       f1    f2    f3
```

You could also do it this way, which is much simpler:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = []
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        # Don't do anything to the field names
        if i == 0:
            new_line = line.rstrip()
        else:
            n_leading_spaces = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
            # Impute periods for spaces
            new_line = line.lstrip().rjust(len(line), '.').rstrip()
        data.append(new_line)
```

Comment: `len(line) - len(line.lstrip())` is clever and I don't why I did not think of it. Thanks for the answer.