# Replace leading whitespace with other other char - Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I want to replace my leading whitespace with a `nbsp;` per whitespace.

So:

```
spam --> spam
 eggs --> &nbsp;eggs
  spam eggs --> &nbsp;&nbsp;spam eggs
```

I've seen a couple of solutions using regex, but all are in other languages.
I've tried the following in Python but with no luck.

```
import re

raw_line = '  spam eggs'

line = re.subn('\s+', '&nbsp;', raw_line, len(raw_line))
print(line) # outputs &nbsp;&nbsp;spam&nbsp;eggs

line = re.sub('\s+', '&nbsp;', raw_line)
print(line) # outputs &nbsp;&nbsp;spam&nbsp;eggs

line = re.sub('^\s', '&nbsp;', raw_line)
print(line) # outputs &nbsp; spam eggs

line = re.sub('^\s+', '&nbsp;', raw_line)
print(line) # outputs &nbsp;spam eggs
```

Last line seems to be closest, but yet no cigar.

What is the proper way to replace each leading whitespace with `&nbsp;` in Python?

If there is a clean way to do this without regex, I will gladly accept, but I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Comment: With `regex` PyPi library, it is as easy as `regex.sub(r'\G\s', '&nbsp;', s)`. With `re`, you need a kind of a `re.sub(r'^ +', lambda x: x.group().replace(' ', '&nbsp;'), s)`

Comment: There is an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555420/3832970

Comment: Took you a while searching for it.. Must say it may answer the direct question, but the title convention is not very effective on searching is it?

Comment: Actually, it took me 20 seconds to find it. No idea if the title is good or bad.

Comment: Well, nicely done then. I couldn't find it for half an hour. But I guess I need to sharpen my stack search skills then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need *expensive* regex here, just strip out the leading whitespace and prepend a number of `&nbsp;` characters for the number of stripped characters:

```
def replace_leading(source, char="&nbsp;"):
    stripped = source.lstrip()
    return char * (len(source) - len(stripped)) + stripped

print(replace_leading("spam"))         # spam
print(replace_leading(" eggs"))        # &nbsp;eggs
print(replace_leading("  spam eggs"))  # &nbsp;&nbsp;spam eggs
```

Comment: Nice! I tried it without regex but couldn't figure it out. Went with your solution because I believe in the fact that if it can be done without regex, do it! In my opinion, not using regex is more readable and maintainable so by default more pythonic

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a callback function and evaluate the length of the match:

```
>>> raw_line = '  spam eggs'
>>> re.sub(r"^\s+", lambda m: "&nbsp;" * len(m.group()), raw_line)
'&nbsp;&nbsp;spam eggs'
```

Answer (score 1):

With [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module (answered in comment by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew))

```
>>> import regex
>>> line = 'spam'
>>> regex.sub(r'\G\s', '&nbsp;', line)
'spam'

>>> line = ' eggs'
>>> regex.sub(r'\G\s', '&nbsp;', line)
'&nbsp;eggs'

>>> line = '  spam eggs'
>>> regex.sub(r'\G\s', '&nbsp;', line)
'&nbsp;&nbsp;spam eggs'
```

From documentation:

> \G
>
> A search anchor has been added. It matches at the position where each
>   search started/continued and can be used for contiguous matches or in
>   negative variable-length lookbehinds to limit how far back the
>   lookbehind goes

Answer (score 0):

A non `regex` solution:

```
s = '  spam eggs'
s_s = s.lstrip()
print('&nbsp;'*(len(s) - len(s_s)) + s_s)
# &nbsp;&nbsp;spam eggs
```